GNS3 Custom Installation with Powershell
I'm using SCCM to deploy GNS3 to a lab and am running the installation silently. I need to modify some of the options that are available in the interactive GUI setup but cant seem to track down how to do this. I was able to accomplish a custom installation of GIT for windows using an INF file, but cant seem to find any sort of similar method with doing this for GNS3 on windows 11. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Every installer will have its own methods for passing arguments. If you can at least identify the type of packager the installer is using, that may help, as these will often have standard arguments. Have you checked GNS3 support or documentation?

@music2myear the documentation doesn't really get into that kind of stuff as far as I can tell. I believe the installer is using NSIS, although I'm not knowledgeable enough to know quite what that means.
I've heard chocolatey mentioned a few times for managing a custom installation, but i'm not sure if that would fit my situation. Thoughts?

So, start looking for "NSIS installer arguments" and "install gns3 chocolatey". Another more niche angle you could take would be to look for people installing GNS3 using SCCM, as these will often have very thoroughly unattended installation arguments.
